# error There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first vb.net "RD = CMD.ExecuteReader"

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```vb
Sub CariData()
    CMD = New MySqlCommand("Select * from tbanggota where nomoragt='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", conn)
    RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
    RD.Read()
    If RD.HasRows Then
        LblNamaAgt.Text = RD.Item("namaagt")
        CMD = New MySqlCommand("Select SUM(totalpjm) AS KETEMU FROM tbpinjam WHERE Nomoragt='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", conn)
        RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
        RD.Read()
        LblTelahPjm.Text = RD.Item(0)
        If LblTelahPjm.Text = 0 Then
            MsgBox("" & LblNamaAgt.Text & " tidak punya pinjaman")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Nomor anggota tidak teRDaftar")
        ComboBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call Pinjaman()
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, questions that contain just code are not acceptable.  You ALWAYS need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  It's good that you provided the error message and it's good that you provided relevant code but they should both be in the question, along with a description of exactly what you're trying to achieve, exactly how you're trying to achieve it and exactly what happens when you try it.  The title should be a summary of the problem.

Comment: As for the issue, the error message is fairly clear: you can't open a data reader on a connection when another data reader is already open.  You need to either close the first data reader before opening the second or else use a different connection.  The fact that you're not closing either data reader at shows that you haven't really done your research properly.  ALWAYS close a data reader when you're done with it.  Preferably open it with a `Using` statement so it is implicitly closed at the `End Using` line.

Answer (score 0):

The error provided in the title is pretty explanatory.

You are sharing the `conn` variable between your two Commands. This is fine if your queries are sequential and closed between them. In your case you should create two different connections and pass them to your commands. I do not know your whole application but in general it is good practice to create/dispose of your connections and commands at the smallest scope possible, and not let them live for a long time.

```
Sub CariData()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
        conn.Open()
        Using CMD As New SqlCommand("Select * from tbanggota where nomoragt='" & Combobox1.Text & "'", conn)
            Using RD As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader
                RD.Read()
                If RD.HasRows Then
                    LblNamaAgt.Text = RD.Item("namaagt")
                    Using innerconn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
                        innerconn.Open()
                        Using innerCMD As New SqlCommand("Select SUM(totalpjm) AS KETEMU FROM tbpinjam WHERE Nomoragt='" & Combobox1.Text & "'", innerconn)
                            Using innerRD As SqlDataReader = innerCMD.ExecuteReader
                                innerRD.Read()
                                LblTelahPjm.Text = innerRD.Item(0)
                                If LblTelahPjm.Text = 0 Then
                                    MsgBox("" & LblNamaAgt.Text & " tidak punya pinjaman")
                                Else
                                    MsgBox("Nomor anggota tidak teRDaftar")
                                    Combobox1.Focus()
                                    Exit Sub
                                End If
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End If
                Call Pinjaman()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Also it seems like your queries are not dependent on each other and can be run sequentially with the same connection if written like the following:

```
Sub CariData()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
        conn.Open()
        Using CMD As New SqlCommand("Select * from tbanggota where nomoragt='" & Combobox1.Text & "'", conn)
            Using RD As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader
                RD.Read()
                If RD.HasRows Then
                    LblNamaAgt.Text = RD.Item("namaagt")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Using CMD As New SqlCommand("Select SUM(totalpjm) AS KETEMU FROM tbpinjam WHERE Nomoragt='" & Combobox1.Text & "'", conn)
            Using RD As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader
                RD.Read()
                LblTelahPjm.Text = RD.Item(0)
                If LblTelahPjm.Text = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("" & LblNamaAgt.Text & " tidak punya pinjaman")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Nomor anggota tidak teRDaftar")
                    Combobox1.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Call Pinjaman()
    End Using
End Sub
```